# I want to run sbt dist and stop the process before packaging

Tags: playframework

I am building my play(java) project using sbt dist which creates a zip file. My zip file contains other folders like bin lib. I want these folders in unzipped folder. Can I use some other command or change my build.sbt so that I don't need to unzip the folder made after sbt dist .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sbt stage`, you will have what you want in the `target/universal/stage` folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm using simple bash script for this in root folder of the project  (Unix, Play 2.4):

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -fr target/universal/*
./activator dist
cd target/universal/
unzip *.zip
cd -
```

Note that `stage` command *may* differ from `dist` (as it was noticed several times in history)